# how to render sprites from a spritesheet

Tags: python, sprite, python-imaging-library, crop, blit

I'm using python to develop a 2d game and am trying to use a spritesheet to optimize performance rather than storing/using dozens of separate sprites. 
The issue I'm having is after calling:

```
Image.crop((x, y, x+62, y+32))
```

I cant seem to use the return from the crop call to draw an image (`canvas.create_image`) and it doesn't seem to be a valid argument in creating a `Photo Image`.

I've looked online to try and figure out how I can use a cropped section of my spritesheet and render it on screen but all I find is `pygame` examples (I'm not using `pygame` in this project and adding it to take advantage of the blit function seems like the wrong way to go).

Does anyone have any recommendations on how I should go about cropping sprites from a spritesheet so I can render them to the `canvas`??

** Edit **
I figured it out, if I pass the crop return value as an arg when creating TkImage.PhotoImage (not just PhotoImage) it works fine

Comment: do you use `Tkinter` ? `PIL` has `Image` and `ImageTk` to create `PhotoImage` for `Tkinter`. http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm

Comment: I use tkinter/PIL but when I pass the crop functions return in to canvas.create_image's image arg or try to use it as the argument when creating a new image variable I get an error, I believe it was something like "can't use string as it implicitly" for both attempts

Comment: As int** implicitly

Comment: add full error message (traceback) in question (not in comment) - it can has more usefull information and it will be more readble and other poeple can read it.

Comment: Fair point I'll add it when I get home from work. Thank you for the advice